# saved image can't open saved image on node server

Tags: node.js, file

I post formdata which includs image file to node server.

This is server request code.

```
const multer = require('multer')
const avatar = multer({dest: 'public/avatar/'})
app.post('/uploadPhoto', avatar.single('file'), function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.file)
})
```

This is console result.

```
  file: {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'git - Copy.jpg',     
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'public/avatar/',      
    filename: 'ac578f8b2b1a629c89f85d3a7215ed18',
    path: 'public\\avatar\\ac578f8b2b1a629c89f85d3a7215ed18',
    size: 4786565
  }
```

And I can see `public/avatar/ac578f8b2b1a629c89f85d3a7215ed18` on my computer.
But I can't open it.
How to convert request file data to correct image type data.

Now if I try to open it, I can get this sentence.

```
The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.
```

Comment: _mimetype: 'image/jpeg'_(looks okay to me). Did you try appending image extension to the filename? Or maybe open the file using any ImageViewer instead of code editor..

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the extension of the file we are trying to save. You can use the diskstorage engine to have more control over how files are stored in the disk.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req,file,callback){
                     const path = `/public/avatar/`;
                     callback(null, path);
           },
      filename: function(req,file,callback){
                    callback(null,`${file.originalname}`);
       }});
```

In the file object, we have all the properties of file like originalname and we can use this to set filename.

Finally, pass this in multer

```
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```